# org.apache.poi.EncryptedDocumentException: Unsupported hash algorithm

Tags: java, apache-poi

I was trying to read a standard password protected Microsoft Excel Worksheet when I get the error:

```
org.apache.poi.EncryptedDocumentException: Unsupported hash algorithm
```

I've been following the standard procedure for xlsx files:

```
POIFSFileSystem fs = new POIFSFileSystem(new FileInputStream(file));
EncryptionInfo info = new EncryptionInfo(fs); // exception strikes here
Decryptor d = Decryptor.getInstance(info);
```

What can I do ?

Comment: Which version of Apache POI is this with? And if it isn't the most recent, did you try upgrading?

Comment: This is the latest version -  POI 3.9 jar I got from maven repository

Comment: Please note that the latest version is POI 3.13, also on Maven, please try using that one as there have been lots and lots of changes in that area since POI 3.9.

Answer (score 1):

The document at http://poi.apache.org/encryption.html describes which encryption formats are support in the current release of Apache POI.

The latest version of Apache POI is actually 3.13, not 3.9. It should be available on Maven as well.

Please try to use the latest version, if your file is encrypted with any of the supported algorithms, it should work.